# Capacitors in an AC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

Can I combine capacitors in the same way for an AC circuit as I can for a DC circuit (In series or in parallel)? Does the same apply for simplifying resistors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, yes. Capacitors can be used in series or in parallel, although for a DC circuit they would prevent current flow in the long term; when the potential difference produced by the capacitor matched the p.d. of the power supply - battery or rectifier.

In an AC circuit they provide *impedance* limiting current without dissipating energy as a resistor would.

Comment: So instead of dealing with each capacitor's individual impedance 1/(wC), I can combine them and treat them as one capacitor? I understand that the impedance of a capacitor depends on the frequency of the alternating current. If I have two capacitors in parallel is the impedance of both 1/(w(C1+C2))?

Comment: Yes, capacitors in parallel simply add: X=1/wC , where C = C1 + C2.